# What is the syntax for this closure for fetchDatabaseChangesResultBlock?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

iOS Cloudkit FetchDatabaseChangesOperation() has a closure block defined as:

```
fetchDatabaseChangesResultBlock: ((_ operationResult:
    Result<(serverChangeToken: CKServerChangeToken, moreComing: Bool), Error>) -> Void)?
```

My question is, what does an actual closure block look like?

For example, I tried this, which compiles:

```
let operation = CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation(previousServerChangeToken: changeToken)

operation.fetchDatabaseChangesResultBlock = {
    result in
}
```

In need to get the serverChangeToken, the moreComing value, and the Error. But I can't figure out what "result" is, or even if I have the right signature.

Any help would be appreciated! I can't figure this one out.

Followup: based on the answer, here is the concrete code that solved the problem.

```
operation.fetchDatabaseChangesResultBlock = {
            result in
            
            switch result {
            case .success(let tuple):
                let token = tuple.serverChangeToken
                let moreComing = tuple.moreComing
                  // Do something
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                // Handle error
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Instead of integrating the answer within your own question, it's better and expected to answer your own question in a separate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you saw, closure's type is `(Result<(serverChangeToken: CKServerChangeToken, moreComing: Bool), Error>) -> Void)?`. Breaking that down we see:

1. The whole thing is optional, meaning it can be `nil`.
2. When it's not `nil`, it's a closure of type `(Result<(serverChangeToken: CKServerChangeToken, moreComing: Bool), Error>) -> Void`.
3. This closure type has one parameter, and doesn't return anything.
4. The parameter has type `Result<(serverChangeToken: CKServerChangeToken, moreComing: Bool), Error>`. This is the [`Result`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result) type from the Swift standard library, whose:

   - `Success` type is `(serverChangeToken: CKServerChangeToken, moreComing: Bool)` (just a tuple of two values)
   - `Failure` type is just `Error` (i.e. it's not constrained anymore than the `Failure: Error` constraint that `Result` already has in place).

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I updated the post with the concrete code that I ended up with.